# jade mixin with dynamic js object variable as attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I am trying to call a mixin in jade like this

```
    +projectInfo("assets/images/image.jpg",{{repository.project[projectId].unit}})
```

> error: `Unexpected token {
>       at Function (native) at assertExpression ...`

I have also tried like this:

```
+projectInfo("assets/images/image.jpg",repository.project[projectId].unit)
```

> error: `Cannot read property 'project' of undefined`

what am I doing wrong?

**update**: mixin looks like this

```
mixin projectInfo(img, title)
    .container-fluid
        .col-xs-12.projectInfo
            .col-xs-12.img
                img(src= img)
            .col-xs-12.title
                h1= title
```

Comment: hi, can you please post also the mixin definition?

Comment: @rick cannot see how that would help but added above

Comment: Understanding the parameters neede maybe???

Comment: So you are trying to send 3 arguments to a method that ask for 2 and clearly your repository object is undefined

Comment: @rick updated. that's not the problem. the problem comes from passing 'repository.project[projectId].unit' I can pass only 'repository' but then I cannot access the unit there

Comment: repository is still undefined?

Comment: for testing I have put the exact same variable into a h1 in the line before calling the mixin and there I am getting a string output.

Comment: ok, that's a different story try silly workaround, set repository.project[projectId].unit to a variable and pass that variable to the mixin

Comment: it's the same problem: if I use repository.project[projectId].unit it says it cannot read property of undefined. if I use just repository it shows me that that's an [object Object]

Comment: try with testVar= repository.project[projectId].unit and then  +projectInfo("assets/images/image.jpg",testVar)

Comment: that's what I did. it throws an error "cannot read property 'project' of undefined"

Comment: than I really cannot understand how you can print that in a h1 I'm sorry, without a fiddle for trying out I'm out of ideas sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115368/discussion-between-sumi-and-rick).

Comment: I would totally make a fiddle if I could figure how to use jade in there.... adding it in the sources doesn't seem to be enough

Answer (score 0):

When you are using AngularJS with Jade, it's better to use directives with own template (powered by Jade if you want as well)

The case you are using it is not really right, jade will be build as html and in that process the value that passed to mixin will be used to draw mixin template instead of `+mixinName()`, and as you want to put dynamic value there it's necessary to use AngularJs approach:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('projectInfo', projectInfo);

function projectInfo() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',

        //build from jade template and contain {{info.title}}, {{info.img}}
        templateUrl: '/templates/myTemplate.html', 

        scope: {info: '='}
    };
}
```